# Softkeyword overlaps bottom button when displayed in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want the soft keyboard to show below the bottom button in my BottomSheet when active, basically moving the BottomSheet up. Currently, it sort of does this but it overlaps the button below the EditText view, so the top of the keyboard limits with the bottom of the EditText view that is receiving input.

[image]

**Here is the bottom_sheet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="90dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="Recupera tu contraseña"
       style="@style/BigSectionTitleText"
       android:textSize="22sp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Ingresa el correo electrónico con que te registraste en Así de Rápido, allí te enviaremos las instrucciones sobre como recuperar tu contraseña."
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/BigSectionTitleText"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Dirección de correo electrónico"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/log_rounded_corners"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_solicitar_correo_cambiar_contrasena"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Pedir"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_zelle_payment_carrito"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**The androidmanifest.xml file for the activity:**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.asiderapido.deliveryapp.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

**The fragment of the sheet:**

```
private var botonRecibirCorreo: MaterialButton? = null

class RecuperarContraseñaBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

// get the views and attach the listene

        var root =  inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.register_bottom_sheet, container,
            false
        )

        botonRecibirCorreo = root.findViewById(R.id.button_solicitar_correo_cambiar_contrasena)
        botonRecibirCorreo!!.setOnClickListener(){
            Toast.makeText(
                root.context,
                "OK",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }

        return  root
    }

    companion object {


        fun newInstance(): RecuperarContraseñaBottomSheet {
            return RecuperarContraseñaBottomSheet()
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is how I call the bottom_sheet fragment in the activity:**

```
  recuperarContrasena = findViewById(R.id.view_recuperar_contraseña)
        recuperarContrasena!!.setOnClickListener(){
            val addPhotoBottomDialogFragment = RecuperarContraseñaBottomSheet.newInstance()
            addPhotoBottomDialogFragment.show(
                supportFragmentManager,
                "add_photo_dialog_fragment"
            )
        }
```